# Process.WaitForExitAsync stucks infinitely while calling ffmpeg on Windows

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I am working with `ffmpeg` via C#'s Process class.

I have a script that runs ffmpeg to generate thumbnails from video. Initially it was called manually from command line - `.\ffmpeg.exe -i .\input.mp4 -ss 00:00:01.000 -vframes:v 1 output.png`, it starts ffmpeg instance, outputs some warnings/errors during the execution:

```
[image2 @ 000001e51095ec80] The specified filename 'output.png' does not contain an image sequence pattern or a pattern is invalid.
[image2 @ 000001e51095ec80] Use a pattern such as %03d for an image sequence or use the -update option (with -frames:v 1 if needed) to write a single image.
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:73kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

but anyway exits the process and correctly generates thumbnail image at output.png.

I want to execute it from C#.
Let's see the code:

```
var ffmpegProcess = new Process
{
     StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
     {
         FileName = _config.FfmpegExecutablePath,
         Arguments = CreateArgumentsForFfmpegProcessToRun(videoTempFilePath, thumbnailTempFilePath),
         RedirectStandardError = true,
         RedirectStandardInput = true,
         RedirectStandardOutput = true,
         UseShellExecute = false,
         CreateNoWindow = true
     },
     EnableRaisingEvents = true
 };

 ffmpegProcess.Start();
 await ffmpegProcess.WaitForExitAsync();
```

Method `CreateArgumentsForFfmpegProcessToRun` returns exactly the same arguments as in the script above `-i .\input.mp4 -ss 00:00:01.000 -vframes:v 1 output.png`.

However, when I run this code, it stucks/blocked at line `ffmpegProcess.WaitForExitAsync()` infinitely and no output written to output path.
If I omit `WaitForExitAsync` call and just go to the next line, then it doesn't stuck and writes the output as expected and finish the process with -1 exit code.

I am trying to figure out why block/stuck happens and what is the best way to resolve this situation? As far I know, `WaitForExitAsync` should return as process ends, no matter how process ends - 0 or another exit code, am I right?

Update #1:
Community advised to search if somewhere up the stack I am blocking my code. I wrote xunit-test and it still stucks.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("assets/input.mp4", "assets/ffmpeg.exe")]
public async Task CreateThumbnailFromVideo(string videoFilePath, string ffmpegExePath)
{
    var config = new VideoThumbnailServiceConfig
    {
         FfmpegExecutablePath = ffmpegExePath,
         ThumbnailImageExtension = ".png"
    };

    var sut = new VideoThumbnailService(config);

    using var fileStream = File.OpenRead(videoFilePath);
    await sut.CreateThumbnailFromVideo(fileStream);
 }
```

Inside `sut.CreateThumbnailFromVideom` I call process start method and awaits `WaitForExitAsync()`.

Comment: Is everything up the chain also async? That is to say: is the method that calls `ffmpegProcess.WaitForExitAsync` async, is the method that calls that async, is the method that calls that also async, etc.?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, yeah, I've already double-checked async/await's correctness

Comment: Search your code for the words `.Wait()`, `.Result` and `.GetResult()`. Can you find any? If you do, you are [blocking on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: Generally speaking, you need to continuously read from stdout and stderr until the process completes. And some processes require you to close stdin as an indicator you are ready for them to exit.

Comment: @StephenCleary, wow, sounds like an idea, thanks! I'll try.